# how to import package that are from another subfolder within a parent folder?

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have the following structure:

```
Repository/
└── D_365/
    ├── Code/
    │   ├── app.py
    │   └── functions/
    │       └── _00_P.py
    └── app_modules/
        └── test.py
```

I want to import the "_00_P.py" in "test.py".

I have tried using several different ways such as from ..Code.functions import _00_P however, I get error "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

I don't want to use the following.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/parent/directory')  # Replace with the actual parent directory path
```

I want to create a virtual environment and properly import the function. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried importing like this: `from ..Code.functions import _00_P`?

Comment: yes but I get error "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: In my understanding, relative import only works in python packages. You would need to add `__init__.py` in some directories to make `D_365` as a whole package. Besides, if you are writing tests for your code, maybe it is easier to put them in the same directory.

Comment: I did create __init__.py in D_365 but it did not work. The example of the folder I have given is just for sample. I actually have got lots of code so I am past the testing stage.

Comment: If you don't want to use this method, you can package your code as a python package, create and edit the setup.py file, and execute`pip install -e .`

Comment: How can I do that? Is there any documentation that I can follow? I’m which directory do I need to create the setup.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relatives import in python cause a lot of problems and I usually only ever use things like `from .my_module import my_func` when I just want something from a file in the same directory.

For everything more complex I would advice making a package out of it and using imports relative to the package. This can be done quite easy.

First you need to add some `__init__.py` in every directory which should belong to the package. The file itself can be empty. So just create an empty `__init__.py` and copy it everywhere.

```
Repository/
├── setup.py
└── D_365/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── Code/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── app.py
    │   └── functions/
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── _00_P.py
    └── app_modules/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test.py
```

Technically you do not need one in `app_modules`, if nothing wants to import anything from `app_modules` but it does not really hurt to have one there.

The setup.py can be very simple and look like this.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='D_365',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

Now just open a terminal go into where the `setup.py` is and run

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

This will install the package making it generally available in the current python environment. The `-e` causes only a link to be installed, instead of all files, so you can change the code in the package without needing to reinstall it to see the changes. It is quite important to not forget the `-e` here or you might be confused later why changes you made to your code do not do anything.

If you have done this you can import like you can with any other python package so in the `test.py` you can do

```
from D_365.code.functions._00_P import ...
```

It is always a bit of overhead doing this but it is really the best way to do what you are trying to do. Also has the nice side effect that all imports are very readable and it is clear where something is coming from. Also you can now use your code in any other python file without problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That seems to solve my problem. Also, couple of questions regarding this method:
1) When I create a new python file e.x. new_file.py in the D_365/Code/functions folder do I need to re run any commands like python -m pip install -e .?
2) This code sits on Git. If another users pulls my code, do they have to do any setup like I had to do or will the code simply work on their laptop without any steps?
3) When I create new folder or file anywhere within D_365 do I need to do anything to import the file anywhere?

Comment: Generally with `-e` you basically never have to rerun the install. You can add, delete files, folders anything. All the `-e` does really is link your package dir and whatever changes inside the dir does not break the install. You need to rerun the install if you do not use `-e`  e.g. creating a wheel for distribution or something. If someone downloads the code they have to run the setup.py somehow to use the code, preferably via pip.  You can distribute the package via pypi if you want, so people can just do `pip install my_package` and use it, without needed to do anything more.

Comment: My company won’t allow me to publish the package. If someone has cloned my repository, will they be able to run the run the test.py without any setup or do they have to run python -m pip install -e .

Comment: They need to run the pip install before. But this is completely normal procedure. You download a repo run some install commands and then you can use it. Some companies have internal pypi repositories where you can maybe publish, but for the most part I am also used to just having a git repo and installing it manually.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for that information. Would they need to run pip install D_365 or pip install -e .

Comment: Generally you just want to run `pip install -e .` where the setup.py is.